# making a TSQL statement that has variables to be dynamic

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am having a real hard time trying to convert a TSQL statement (which be a store procedure) into a Dynamic SQL. Basically I must be able to pass the schema name as a parameter.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @query AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @schemaName AS varchar(5) = 'wl03' -- To be used later as a parameter in stored procedure
DECLARE @plus11Month AS DATE = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+11, 0) AS DATE) --The 11th month from the current month
DECLARE @plus12Month AS DATE = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+12, 0) AS DATE) --The 12th month from the current month

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #12thMonthExpectedActivity

-- Add rows for existing month into a temporary table
-- The code below returns an error: The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.
SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @plus12Month + 'AS period, genusId, subjectId, waitingStageId, value, ' + GETDATE() + ' AS savedOn, ''<Automated>'' AS savedBy INTO #12thMonthExpectedActivity FROM [' + @schemaName + '].[ExpectedActivity]
WHERE period in(' + @plus11Month + ')'
-- EXEC(@query) will go here once the above is working

/* This original code works just fine!
SELECT @plus12Month AS period, genusId, subjectId, waitingStageId, value, GETDATE() AS savedOn, '<Automated>' AS savedBy INTO #12thMonthExpectedActivity FROM [wl03].[ExpectedActivity]
  WHERE period in(@plus11Month)
*/
```

The problem I have is defining the `@query` variable. I keep getting the same error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 The data types varchar and date are
>   incompatible in the add operator.

The code does work fine as long as I don't try to save it in a query. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates must be strings too, but in a format that is unambiguous (e.g. date format 112):

```
DECLARE @plus11Month AS CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+11, 0) AS DATE), 112) --The 11th month from the current month
DECLARE @plus12Month AS CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+12, 0) AS DATE), 112) --The 12th month from the current month
```

You will need to convert your `GETDATE()` as well, where you have it in the string. Watch out for quotation marks, and casting back to `DATE` as well. Here's a proposed solution:

```
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @schemaName AS VARCHAR(5) = 'wl03'; -- To be used later as a parameter in stored procedure
DECLARE @plus11Month AS CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 11, 0) AS DATE), 112); --The 11th month from the current month
DECLARE @plus12Month AS CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 12, 0) AS DATE), 112); --The 12th month from the current month
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #12thMonthExpectedActivity;

-- Add rows for existing month into a temporary table
SET @query
    = 'SELECT CAST(''' + @plus12Month + ''' AS DATE) AS period, genusId, subjectId, waitingStageId, value, CAST('''
      + CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
      + ''' AS DATE) AS savedOn, ''<Automated>'' AS savedBy INTO #12thMonthExpectedActivity FROM [' + @schemaName
      + '].[ExpectedActivity] WHERE period in (''' + @plus11Month + ''')';

PRINT @query;
```

Read more about `CAST` and `CONVERT` with [Books Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

Comment: Thanks! But now I got another error, which I was expecting: **The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.**

Comment: Ugh! I am still having the same error :( https://pastebin.com/QbrvZuRR

Comment: Doh! My bad. The code seems to work now but if I try to do `select * from #12thMonthExpectedActivity` it tell me that the object does not exist?! what the heck... :(  https://pastebin.com/mgyDCfJy

Comment: Oh crap. dynamics SQL is such a PAIN! Problem is that after I create the temp table, I need to insert those values on another table, and that is another statement! how can I ensure the table keeps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61725/discussion-between-randolph-west-and-pmdci).

Comment: Either way, you did solve the one problem I raised, so kudos on that :)